# counting specific value in data frame and create new column having sum of it

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hi I have counted sum of occurrence of NAs (missing value) in entire data frame and save it to new column using code.

```
df$NAS<-sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
a1<-data.frame(a)
```

I am wondering if i want to get sum of occurrence of specific entry in column eg. "unspecified" in column then how to twig this code or any other option to do that.

Comment: Then you can do `function(x) sum(x=="unspecified", na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: thank you ....it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(x=='unspecified', rm.na=TRUE))
```

**Explanation:**

The function `is.na(x)` returns a vector with `TRUE` or `FALSE` entries, depending on whether a value is `NA` or not. By summing over that vector we get the number of `TRUE` in your vector. This is what you currently have.

If we replace `is.na(x)`, with a function that displays the same behaviour but for values other than `NA`, we have solved your problem.

The most obvious way to do this, is a function that checks whether every value is equal to 'unspecified':

```
val_check <- function(x) x == 'unspecified'
```

If we use this in `sapply` and sum over it, we're done, right? Now, there is one more thing that's going to cause trouble, and that is the occurrence of `NA`. Summing over a vector that contains `NA` results in an `NA`:

```
sum(c(1, 2, 3, NA))
# [1] NA
```

By adding the option `na.rm = TRUE` we overcome this problem:

```
sum(c(1, 2, 3, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 7
```

So, `sapply(df, function(x) sum(x=='unspecified', rm.na=TRUE))` is the answer you're looking for